# update item Sharepoint Choice Field

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a list in Sharepoint 2010 with a choice column. User can enter own text value, not to choose from existing values.

So how to write text string in item field (type Choice) if this string is different from the existing values? Programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set it as a string. That's how the values of choice fields are stored internally.

```
SPListItem item = ...
item["ChoiceFieldInternalName"] = "Whatever value you want";
item.Update();
```

Now, if it were a lookup field, or a user field, they're a little different (You'd have to decoded the string using a SPFieldLookupValue or SPFieldUserValue object, for example), but Choice is easy enough.